# Phone Conversation: "Are you going to hang up or will you .....?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

When, in the middle of a phone conversation, you should do something meanwhile the person you're talking to is holding, and you want to know if she/he would rather hold or hang up and call back sometime later, what phrases can you use to inquire this information? Or simply put, what's the opposite of the phrase "hang up" people use in everyday conversation. I'm basically looking for more of a conversational/informal way to ask this than ***Are you going to hold?***

Comment: "Are you going to hang up, or will you hang on?"

Comment: "sorry, it's taking a bit longer on the other call.. can I call you back or do you want to keep waiting for x or y minutes?" I think offering to call someone back is expected and polite ... my 2cents opinion there of course... If you Want them to hold on (perhaps it would be difficult to reach them again) and willing to ask them to do so... "can you hold on for a few minutes please?" .  "Are you going to hold?" doesn't give them any indication of what you'd hope for or extend the courtesy of asking for what they'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you going to wait on the line?

is what I would say.